# Flash SWF, reading the file contents from inside the browser, possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I have an actionscript project which I deploy as both a Air desktop application and in the browser using the Flash plugin.

My desktop deployment reads the SWF file itself, creates a hash of the file and send it to my server. If the hash does not match whats expected the SWF then uploads itself to my server for further examination. This all uses the flash.filesystem libraries.

Can the same be done when deployed as Flash file in the browser. I do not have access to flash.filesystem for browser deployment.

Does a way other than using filesystem exist to read the SWF itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this article (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) your entire SWF content is accessible via **loaderInfo.bytes**:**ByteArray** so there's no need to load anything. Enjoy.

Fallback to loading:

```
var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;

// Property loaderInfo.url contains the full path to the SWF.
aRequest.url = loaderInfo.url;

var aLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

// Set data format to binary instead of default text.
aLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
aLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onReady);
aLoader.load(aRequest);

function onReady(e:Event):void
{
    var anSWF:ByteArray = aLoader.data as ByteArray;
    trace(anSWF.length);
}
```

Comment: Great, loaderInfo.bytes contains the actual swf data itself, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: On further examination I found the following, the actual swf itself and the contents on loaderInfo.bytes are different, this is because loaderInfo.bytes contains a decompressed version.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok, added loading solution. Pity loaderInfo.bytes didn't work.

Comment: it does not matter, I just made the comment should someone be confused at why the files are different.

Answer (score 1):

To get the SWF bytes, use [**URLStream**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) API to receive bytes into some `bytearray` variable.

You can then use [**ByteArray**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) API to read (process) the `bytearray`.

Comment: Thanks, but am I correct in thinking that such a method is reliant on you specifying the location of the swf. And even if you read the location of the file you will be reliant on the browser telling you? This I think is somewhat different to the desktop implementation, because I ask for the location of the actual swf thats doing the asking, so I have some certainly that I am reading the correct file.

Comment: See above comments ref loaderInfo.bytes.

Comment: Regardless there are simpler solution for the case, URLStream is unnecessary as you need the whole content anyway. URLLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your Flex code to an AIR desktop application, which is translated to a SWF file, which can be used in browsers as an embedded object.
Please read more [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc4c0afd1212601c9a36f-8000.html).